# cant grap img src and assign it to a div as BG in jquery?

Tags: jquery

hi this is the jquery code :

```
$(".c").mouseover(function() {
var colorbg = $(".c").attr("src");
$(".colortip").fadeIn(function() {
$(this).html('<img src="' + colorbg + '"/>');
return false;
});`enter code here`
});
```

and HTML is as follows :

```
img ...1
img....2
img ...3
```

what i want to do is to show the the "colortip" div when mouseover any img.c and in the same time i want to assign the img.c images source as a background to the div.colortip

i wrote the code above and it works to show the div but it only assign the BG for the first img with only the first img src and doesnt detect other images src and change it when i hover on other divs with other colors.- so how can i make it each time pushes the new img src as a bg to the div?

your help is much appreciated - Thanks

Comment: Can you try posting your HTML again?  It seems to be missing.

Answer (score 2):

#### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/okaras/edit#javascript,html,live)*

Use `$(this)`

```
var colorbg = '';
$(".c").mouseover(function() {
   colorbg = $(this).attr("src");   // tada!
   $(".colortip").fadeIn(function() {
       $(this).html('<img src="' + colorbg + '"/>');
       return false;
   });
});
```

---

After I used your code, here is how to set the element **CSS background**:

#### *[jsBin demo (set CSS background with jQ)](http://jsbin.com/okaras/2/edit)*

```
var colorbg = '';
$(".c").mouseover(function() {
   colorbg = $(this).attr("src");   // tada!
   $(".colortip").fadeIn(function() {
     $(this).css({background: 'url('+colorbg+')'}); // access element CSS bG. 
       return false;
   });
});
```